# Column of "date" dataType, inserts null value, while inserting value between 0 to 1.. eg 0.08, 0.99 etc

Tags: sql, date, mariadb

```
CREATE TABLE `datesissue` (
  `id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `dates` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `user` varchar(64) COLLATE utf8mb3_bin NOT NULL,
  `modified_user` varchar(64) COLLATE utf8mb3_bin NOT NULL,
  `created_date` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp(),
  `modified_date` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp() ON UPDATE current_timestamp(),
  `system_data_source` varchar(512) COLLATE utf8mb3_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `id` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=6 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb3 COLLATE=utf8mb3_bin



insert into datesissue (dates,user, modified_user) values(0.08,"abc","xyz")

update datesissue set dates = 0.00020596473883443116 where id = 1
```

I expect Database to throw me an error stating

> Incorrect date value: for column `datesissue`.`dates` at row 1

Comment: I'd expect the same... But Mariadb does this in its own way, https://dbfiddle.uk/DnSqgLkQ. Switch to MySQL, and you'll get an exception.

Comment: @jarlh helps when the WHERE criteria matches a row that exists :-), but yes the MySQL and MariaDB `sql_mode` defaults are different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MariaDB preserved the backwards compatibility by default which means invalid dates where accepted.

If you set the SQL_MODE to contain [NO_ZERO_DATE](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/sql-mode/#no_zero_date) (and [NO_ZERO_IN_DATE](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/sql-mode/#no_zero_in_date) while you are at it), a more expected behaviour of an error will occur:

```
MariaDB [test]> set statement sql_mode=concat(@@sql_mode, ",NO_ZERO_DATE,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE") for update datesissue set dates =
0.20596473883443116;
ERROR 1292 (22007): Incorrect date value: '0.20596473883443116' for column `test`.`datesissue`.`dates` at row 1
```